# get related row in many to many relation once

Tags: sql

Ok, I feel like this should be obvious, but I'm not seeing it.  I have a tagging system with two tables (say A and C) related (many-many) through a 3rd table (say B).

I want to select all the unique rows in A that meet a criteria based on a field in C.  That is to say, if the same row in A is tagged with multiple tags in C that meet my criteria, I don't want multiple rows back--just the single row from A.

So I want all rows in A that have tags that meet my criteria based on a field in C.  But I never want a row duplicated in A, even if it has multiple tags that meet the criteria.

Comment: How are the tags laid out? Are they in different rows or in one column? You say you also need the primary key from table C, but if it's a many-to-many relationship, how you do know ***which one*** to include?

Comment: Yea, deleted my comment because I realized that.  Sorry I'm operating on too little sleep.  The proposed solutions will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.id = B.id
    INNER JOIN C
        ON C.id = B.id
WHERE C.SomeField = 'SomeValue'
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to add the `DISTINCT` keyword. In other words change this:

```
SELECT A.foo FROM ...
```

to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.foo FROM ...
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword ensures that you won't get duplicates in the results.

---

An alternative solution is to rewrite your query to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM B
    JOIN C
    ON ...
    WHERE ...
)
```